# I have a sql query which pulls data, however each person can have many numbers which produces multiple rows for each person, i need 1 row per person

Tags: sql, sql-server

Example

my query would produce two rows for bob with the only difference being the telephone number. however the table that i get the telephone numbers from have a telephone type ID. for example the first row for bob the telephone type ID would be 1 and the second row would be 2. I need them both on the same row

I assumed i would need to do a sub query for each telephone ID type...but that doesn't seems to be working. I just keep getting back

Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

[What query produces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvzaI.png)

What i would like my query to produce

[What i need for query to produce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvzaI.png)

Thanks

Comment: Both links lead to same picture.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a limited number of telephone types, you can use a **LEFT OUTER JOIN** on `telephone` table for each types. Ex:

```
SELECT e.name, t1.phoneNumber AS telephone1, t2.phoneNumber AS telephone2, e.email, ...
FROM person AS e
  LEFT OUTER JOIN telephon AS t1 ON t1.personID = e.Id AND typeId = 1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN telephon AS t2 ON t2.personID = e.Id AND typeId = 2
  ...
WHERE ....
```